# How to open SharePoint list row in own HTML page JavaScript?

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-online, splistitem

I have a SharePoint-Hosted app with a survey with textareas and radio buttons. The textareas and radio buttons are connected with columns in a SharePoint list so the user is filling in all boxes and then press a save button to send the data to the list columns. It's a bit complicated to read the answers because it's all on one row.

When you go in to the SharePoint list and want to read the answers is it possible to open it in the same survey page to read the answers?

So when you click on the item you want to see it in the same page you answered it in.

I want to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the site in SharePoint designer , go to your SharePoint List and create a new Display form. In that display form you can re use the same html and JavaScript code of your Survey page. See this [blog](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-custom-list-form-using-SharePoint-Designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105) to know about custom list form.

Comment: Ok but do the anwers so put in show up?

Comment: for that you will need to pass the ID of the survey item clicked in querystring and in that custom display page write jsom to read the data from the list and display

Comment: ok i'am not the best on this could you write an exampel if you have time?